# Django subclassing UserProfile problem

Tags: database, django, django-models

Given the code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # project userprofile, also set as AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

class AppUserProfile(UserProfile):
    # some app specific extension
```

and the test:

```
user = User.objects.create()
profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
AppUserProfile.objects.create(user=user)
```

it fails on the last line, saying:

```
IntegrityError: column user_id is not unique
```

What I suspect is that Django uses the same table for user-userprofile and user-anotheruserprofile relationship defined by ForeignKey.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error is the fact that you are creating two UserProfile-s with the same user_id. You are using "multi-table inheritance", so you only have to call AppUserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user) and it will work as expected.

Documentation for [Django Models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) explains it pretty good.

Comment: Thank you!Ok, I understand the problem, but I'll ask it this way: if I have the UserProfile (from request.user.get_profile), how can I reach the AppUserProfile object) from it?

Comment: what I was searching for, isn't implemented: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7623

Comment: If I understand the docs correctly it should be available as a property on the UserProfile instance, profile.appuserprofile in your case.

Comment: that's true only if the appuserprofile is created before userprofile. learned by testing.